# Cause for a clipped keyboard in landscape

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a page with a Pivot, with TextBox controls. In landscape, the SIP (the virtual keyboard) is opffsetted right by 42 pixels, thus clipped to its right.

[image: Clipped keyboard in landscape]

Another app of mine also has a similar page, without the offsetted keyboard problem. Before I dig more into the differences between the two, has anyone ever encountered this problem before? Can we consider this a bug with Windows Phone 7.1?

(it does occur on a real device too)

Comment: Can you repro with a minimal example?

Comment: Tried backing out your UI until you find the piece that triggers it?  If I had to guess, it would be a style that is applied to all elements of a type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in windows phone:

If you set the Mode property on the app bar to Minimised and then turn the thing to landscape, the app bar pops back out. The code that figures out where to show the keyboard doesn't realise this and displays the keyboard as if the app bar is still minimised.

I solved it by changing the mode of the app bar as the orientation changes:

```
private void phoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft || e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
  {
    this.ApplicationBar.Mode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarMode.Default;
  }
  else
  {
    this.ApplicationBar.Mode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
  }
}
```

This seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you have a set common right offset margin somewhere in your code. That is the most likely reason for this behavior.

I have never experienced this error myself.